# Python factorial and ploting using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

im new to python. im trying to write a fuction that will calculate the factorial function of a number N, then write the data to a csv file. next step is to read the data from the file and plot a log style grap of N vs N!. this is the code that i have so far but it not working. sorry for my ignorance. thank you. i keep getting the error that i and Nfactorial is not defined.

```
def factorial(N):
"""Compute N! = 1*2*...*N and 0!=1 where N >=0 and is an integer. 
Args:
    N: (int) must be >=0
Returns:
    (int) the evaluation of N!
    write the value of N and N! to data.csv file.
Raises:
    ValueError if N is not an integer
    ValueError if N<0 
"""
if type(N) is not int:
    raise ValueError('factorial() only takes integer input')
if N < 0:
    raise ValueError('factorial() only takes integers >= 0')
    Nfactorial = 1
for i in range(0,10):
    Nfactorial *=i
return Nfactorial, i
zip (i, Nfactorial)
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'w') as fh:
writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter = '\t')
for n, m in zip(i,Nfactorial):
    writer.writerow([i,Nfactorial])

def factorialplot():
"""
Take value of N and N! from data.csv file
Args:
plot a  log function of N vs N!
Returns:
a log plot of N vs N!
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
x = []
y = []
with open('datafile.txt','r') as csvfile:
plots = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
plt.plot(x,y, label = 'factorial plot')
plt.xlabel('N!')
plt.ylabel('N')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: First of all your Nfactorial is in the N<0 if block, that is why you are getting the not defined error. Put it outside of that block. Also, i is defined in the for block and hence can't be returned like that.

Comment: Also, post the exact error that you are getting and line numbers if possible. It tells you where exactly the error is.

Comment: Also, is the indentation of the original code same as posted above? Your indentation is completely misplaced. First correct that and then test.

Comment: Everything that @Gourav said and also: Why do you loop from 0 to 9 when calculating `Nfactorial`? If you start by multiplying with `0`, Nfactorial will never be anything else than `0`. The loop also doesn't depend on `N`, which you want it to. `zip` does nothing here, because you don't assign the output to anything (`out=zip(...)`) and is also meaningless, because `i` is 9 after the loop (or `N` if the loop were correct). You do not want to `return` at that point, because the function isn't finished yet and you don't need the function to return anything anyway, because you write in the file.

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new file and copying the code line by line (or more if it's an `if` or `for` loop or such) into it, starting at the top. Then check after every step, if the code (1) still runs, and (2) does what you want it to (either by `print`ing the last value or by using an IDE with a variable inspector or a debugger).